# creating and writing to text file from fully qualified path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a text file, (name is time the script is run), and then write to the text file at a fully qualified path, python doesn't seem to ever like how I write the \ or / or r' ', Either way I can't get the text file to be created, so I can't write to it. Here's my code now:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import os

Today = dt.today()
now = Today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
file = now +'.txt'
path = '\\SERVERNAME\folder\email_output\%s' % (file)
file_output = os.open(path)
```

I'm getting the error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\SERVERNAME\\\folder\\\email_output\\\2020-06-12 16:09.txt'
```

And I need the path to be:`'\\\SERVERNAME\\folder\\email_output\\2020-06-12 16:09.txt'`

Comment: HAve you tried just double escaping all your backslashes? `path = '\\\\SERVERNAME\\folder\\email_output\\%s' % (file)`

Comment: is the path a remote path?

Comment: I have tried double escaping, still results in a n error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\SERVERNAME\\folder\\email_output\\2020-06-12 16:38.txt''@ChrisDoyle

Comment: I don't know what you mean, it is cross mounted with linux, and I'm accessing through windows if that is what you mean @Woops

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import os

Today = dt.today()
now = Today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d H%H M%M')
filename = now +'.txt'

folder_path = r'\\SERVERNAME\folder\email_output'
file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

file = open(file_path, 'w')
file.close()
```

Some suggestions:

1. You used `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'` to write the date and the time as a string for the file name, for example `2020-06-12 23:32.txt`. Some OS does not allow some characters (as `:`, `?`, `*`, `\`, `/` and others) to be used within file name or folder name. I replaced that with `%Y-%m-%d H%H M%M`, so you will have `2020-06-12 H23 M32.txt` for example. You can change this with the format you prefer, but you have to avoid the special characters.
2. A better way to define the file path is to use the `os.path.join()` method, check the [documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/).
3. In Python the `\` inside a string is a special character. If you add a `r` before the string (as `r'C:\Users'`), the `\` is considered a normal character. This is particulary helpful when you define the path of a folder in Windows, where the `\` is used as a folder-subfolder separator.

Comment: this still results in an error: 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\SERVERNAME\\folder\\email_output\\2020-06-12 H16 M39.txt'
I don't think its a problem with the way my datetime is formatted, its to do with the double \\ then single \   @andrea

Comment: Try to check this [documentation](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/) on backslashes in Windows filenames